# Dos scroll jquery uno despues del otro

Tags: jquery, html5, css, scroll

Una duda para JQuery y el scroll vertical: Tengo dos `div`s obvio el primero se encuentra arriba del otro.

```
<div class="uno"></div>
<div class="dos"></div>
```

El problema es que tengo el scroll principal de la ventana, y el el `div.dos` tiene en su interior otro scroll. Lo que quiero hacer es que al dectar el final del `div.uno` éste se sincronice el scroll principal con el del `div.dos`.

Por ejemplo: Tengo lo siguiente

```
    [![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .uno{
        width: 100%;
        height: 450px;
        background: blue;
    }
    .dos{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        background: orange;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="uno"></div>
        <div class="dos">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
            <img src="PERRO.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

[image: Referencia imagen]

En la imagen indico con una flecha que cuando el scroll principal llegue a ese punto se empareje con el otro y los dos funcionen al mismo tiempo, y así de regreso.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. ¿Puedes poner algún ejemplo para que nos sea más fácil ayudarte? En cualquier caso [esta](http://scrollmagic.io) librería siempre es de ayuda con efectos de scroll.

Comment: En el código que has pegado el `<div class="dos">` no tiene scroll interior, simplemente es un `div` que alarga el scroll de la ventana 1000px. Sigo sin entender que quieres conseguir. En las etiquetas has puesto jQuery, ¿En que interviene jQuery en tu proyecto?

Comment: Si claro, mira explico de manera mas sencilla, como ves, tengo dos divs, uno que en mi caso vendría siendo una cabecera y otro que vendría siendo contenido, dentro del contenido cargo un feed de instagram(imagenes) y este al hacer scroll, automaticamente me carga mas imagenes(los 1000px eran como referencia unicamente ya que ese div dos su height es automatico). Entonces necesito de alguna manera que los dos scroll se sincronicen cuando alcanza el tamaño del div.uno para que quede como "pegado" y no me ocasione problemas siendo dos scroll

Comment: Si te he entendido bien creo que lo que quieres conseguir no tiene mucho sentido. ¿Porque limitas el alto del `div.dos` a 1000px? ¿Porque no dejas que crezca al alto que necesite para contener las imágenes?

Comment: En que no tiene sentido? El problema que tengo es que al ser dos scroll, el control se vuelve loco y no puedo mover uno o el otro :S. Como te mencione, el alto solo es para yo ayudarme a que tenga scroll el div, originalmente tiene una altura automatica

Comment: Se me ha ido el dedo a la tecla enter antes de terminar mi respuesta . ¿Lo que intentas es que la 'cabecera' se te quede fija al llegar a cierto punto y que solo haya scroll en el contenedor de las imágenes?

Comment: Aja, creo que si es eso mas o menos. No me importa que no se vea la 'cabecera' lo que me importa es el otro div y que cuando vuelva a regresar, automaticamente en ves de tomar el scroll del div de las imagenes regrese al scroll principal y me muestre la 'cabecera'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44514/discussion-between-eledgaar-and-irwing).